# Make JavaFX window active

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make a JavaFX application (running in the background to show up (set visible)) by a specific keystroke and to make the window the active window immediately. Therefore I set the primary stage alwaysOnTop-property `true`, call `stage.toFront()` and finally call `stage.requestFocus()`. Afterwards I request focus for a text field. When the window is made visible I would like to instantly start typing into the text field.

However, when I for example have a Ubuntu-terminal selected and make the window visible and start typing, the application is shown on top of everything, however, the typing goes to the terminal. The application window is not active! Nevertheless, the focused property of the stage is `true`. Is that a bug or am I missing something? Is it OS related?

---

*Edit:* I am willed to give my little hack-around for this problem that I am using at the moment, because the internet is suggesting, that a lot of people are facing this problem: Since I am working on a linux maschine I have access to the wonderful tool `wmctrl`. It is part of most standard repositories. `wmctrl -a WINDOWNAME` sets the window with the name `WINDOWNAME` active. For now, I simply call this tool from my source code when I need the window to be active. Since this is more of a dirty hack than any thing else, I sure want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect, but it works:

```
Platform.runLater(() ->
{
    //primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    //primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    primaryStage.setIconified(true);
    primaryStage.setIconified(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your node is not getting focused, try wrapping `requestFocus()` in a `Runnable` and call `Platform.runLater()`:

```
final TextField text = new TextField();

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    text.requestFocus();
  }
});
```

Comment: The focused property gets set to true using my methodology explained above. Although the stage is focused, the window is not active.